# Using sed to remove urls with specific anchor text matches

Tags: sed

Trying to parse some spam injection out of a mysql export file, and for some reason this is not working:

```
sed 's|(<a href="http://[^"]*">[^<]*Buy[^<]*</a>)||g'
```

Which, imo, should match and remove:

```
<a href="http://basicpills.com/">Buy Generic Drugs Without Prescription</a>
```

but for some reason isn't. I can do it in perl no prob, since that supports non-greedy matches, but it is so slow, and since I will probably have to do 7 or 8 passes to get all the different permutations it would be much better if I can get sed to work instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not forget -r to support extended regexp: `sed -r 's|(<a href="http://[^"]*">[^<]*Buy[^<]*</a>)||g'` or just remove the useless parenthesis (that should be `\(` and `\)` without `-r`)

Are you sure that `perl -p -e 's|<a href="http://[^"]*">[^<]*Buy[^<]*</a>||g'` is really slower.

Comment: Of course! Thank you! I can't believe I forgot to escape the parenthesis. Works like a charm. :) I can't upvote you till I get more rep, will try and remember to come back though.

Comment: by the way, I missed the second part of your reply yesterday. Yes, the perl solution I was using was extremely slow:

`perl -pe 's|(<a href="http://.*?">.*?Buy.*?</a>)||'`